# parsing json response from serial window

Tags: c++, c, json, arduino, arduino-uno

Hi i'm trying to parse JSON resposne from webserver in my arduino in order to turn on and off a LED light. I'm using the wifi client repeating example to make a get request to my server:

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClientRepeating

Here is what I get printed back from the serial port when I run

```
WiFiClient client;
   char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
```

serial port results

```
connecting...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Apr 2014 01:14:37 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.10
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: expires=Sun, 06-Apr-2014 03:14:37 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

19
{"lightstatus":"on"}
0
```

How do i parse the JSON portion of this response only so that I can use it to control my LED?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not just start the parsing from the json object by having some identifier for the start?

Comment: What do you mean?  Is there a function to get only JSON from the WiFiClient object?

Answer (score 0):

well, even JSON is "hard" to parse for an arduino. So you should consider simplyfying as much as possible the response, by using `1`/`0` integers instead of `"on"` for example.

What you need to run, is basically a state graph:

```
if ('{' == client.read())
  if ('"' == client.read())
    if ('l' == client.read())
      if ('i' == client.read())
        if ('g' == client.read())
          if ('h' == client.read())
            if ('t' == client.read())
              if ('s' == client.read())
                if ('t' == client.read())
                  if ('a' == client.read())
                    if ('t' == client.read())
                      if ('u' == client.read())
                        if ('s' == client.read())
                          if ('"' == client.read())
                            if (':' == client.read()) {
                               char c = client.read();
                               if (c == '1')
                                 // TURN LIGHT ON
                               else if (c == '0')
                                 // TURN LIGHT OFF
                            }
```

which can be improved by using a string, and keeping the state in an index variable:

```
const char* VAL="{\"lightstatus\":"

int parse_value(char c) {
    static int val_idx=0;
    // end of parsing condition, the index reached string length
    if (strlen(VAL) == val_idx) {
        // if the value is '1', return >0, if the value is '0', return 0
        if ('1' == c) return 1;
        else if ('0' == c) return 0;
    }
    // otherwise let's check if we're still in string
    if (c == VAL[val_idx]) {
        // if we do, increment the index variable
        ++val_idx;
    } else {
        // or reset it
        val_idx = 0;
    }
    // return -1 while we're still parsing the string
    return -1;
}
```

to use that code:

```
char val=-1;
while (val < 0)
    val = parse_value(Serial.read())
```

I did not test it, but I hope you get the algorithmic idea!

HTH